# Nginx upload progress module error after file is uploaded

Tags: file-upload, nginx

when i upload a file with nginx upload progress module file starts uploading normally , then i get the progress how much is uploaded , but when the file upload finishes i get  error (`({ "state" : "error", "status" : 17523466568084 });`)

Well , my wild guess is that in my config is specified backend  `upload_pass /upload;` , which i don't have , and everytime it uploads file  at the end it tries to get this backend and gives me error as it doesn't exist. I tried to comment out this line , but then i get another error from nginx  ( **"track_uploads" directive track_upload should be the last directive in the location, after either proxy_pass or fastcgi_pass in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/web-files.com:52**).

1)**So** the first question is what's the error ?

2)**Second** is how can i get those parameters passed from nginx to backend in backend.

Maybe someone has any ideas what's the matter.

My nginx conf:

```
http {
   ...
   upload_progress upload 2m;

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name   mydomain;

    root /home/cha0s/web-files;
    index index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/cha0s/web-files$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;

    }

    location ~ ^/files/(.*)$ {
            alias /home/cha0s/$1;
            internal;
    }

    location = /upload/share {
      client_max_body_size 250m;

      #Specify backend location/url and directory for file upload
      upload_pass /upload;
      upload_store /tmp;

      # Declare variables which are passed to backend
      upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.name "$upload_file_name";
      upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.content_type "$upload_content_type";
      upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.path "$upload_tmp_path";

      upload_aggregate_form_field "$upload_field_name.md5" "$upload_file_md5";
      upload_aggregate_form_field "$upload_field_name.size" "$upload_file_size";


      # Delete uploaded file on error
      upload_cleanup 400 404 499 500-505;

      # Limit upload speed
      upload_limit_rate 8k;


      track_uploads upload 1m;
    }

    location = /upload/status {
      report_uploads upload;
    }

}
}
```

My test.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
      function add() {
        if (parseInt(document.getElementById('count').getAttribute('value')) < 8) {
          var input = document.createElement('input');
          input.setAttribute('type','file');
          input.setAttribute('multiple','');
          input.setAttribute('name','file[]');
          document.getElementById('multiple').appendChild(input);
          document.getElementById('multiple').appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
          document.getElementById('count').setAttribute('value',parseInt(document.getElementById('count').getAttribute('value'))+1);
        }
        else {
          alert('Можно загрузить не более 8 файлов за раз.');
        }
      }
      function progress() {
        var ms = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
        rq = 0;
        id = "";
        for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
          id += Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toString(16);
        }
        document.getElementById('upload').action = "/upload/share?X-Progress-ID=" + id;
        document.getElementById('status').style.display = 'block'
        interval = window.setInterval(function () { fetch(id, ms); }, 1000);
        return true;
      }
      function fetch(id, ms) {
        var fetch = new XMLHttpRequest();
        fetch.open("GET", "/upload/status", 1);
        fetch.setRequestHeader("X-Progress-ID", id);
        fetch.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (fetch.readyState == 4) {
            if (fetch.status == 200) {
              var now = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
              var upload = eval(fetch.responseText);
              if (upload.state == 'uploading') {
                var diff = upload.size - upload.received;
                var rate = upload.received / upload.size;
                var elapsed = now - ms;
                var speed = upload.received - rq; rq = upload.received;
                var remaining = (upload.size - upload.received) / speed;
                var uReceived = parseInt(upload.received) + ' bytes';
                var uDiff = parseInt(diff) + ' bytes';
                var tTotal = parseInt(elapsed + remaining) + ' secs';
                var tElapsed = parseInt(elapsed) + ' secs';
                var tRemaining = parseInt(remaining) + ' secs';
                var percent = Math.round(100*rate) + '%';
                var uSpeed = speed + ' bytes/sec';
                document.getElementById('length').firstChild.nodeValue = parseInt(upload.size) + ' bytes';
                document.getElementById('sent').firstChild.nodeValue = uReceived;
                document.getElementById('offset').firstChild.nodeValue = uDiff;
                document.getElementById('total').firstChild.nodeValue = tTotal;
                document.getElementById('elapsed').firstChild.nodeValue = tElapsed;
                document.getElementById('remaining').firstChild.nodeValue = tRemaining;
                document.getElementById('speed').firstChild.nodeValue = uSpeed;
                document.getElementById('bar').firstChild.nodeValue = percent;
                document.getElementById('bar').style.width = percent
              }
              else {
                window.clearTimeout(interval);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        fetch.send(null);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload" onsubmit="progress();">
      <input type="hidden" id="count" value="1" />
      <div id="multiple">
        <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple /><br>
      </div>
      <input type="submit">
      <a href="#" onclick="add();">add();</a>
    </form>
    <div id="status" style="display: none;">
      <table width="100%"> 
        <tr><th></th><th>загрузка</th><th>осталось</th><th>всего</th></tr>
        <tr><td>время:</td><td id="elapsed">∞</td><td id="remaining">∞</td><td id="total">∞</td></tr>
        <tr><td>размер:</td><td id="sent">0 b</td><td id="offset">0 b</td><td id="length">0 b</td></tr>
        <tr><td>скорость:</td><td id="speed">n/a</td></tr>
      </table>
      <div style="border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;">
        <div style="background: #c0c0c0; width: 0%; text-align: right;" id="bar">0%</div>
      </div>
      <a href="#" onclick="if (confirm('Вы точно хотите отменить загрузку?')) window.location = '/'" id="cancel">cancel_upload();</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok . After some testing am sure that issue is connected to proxy pass .... the only thing i don't understand where this should direct. Basically upload_pass /upload should be right , but as it doesn't exist it fails ..... so then back to square one , what should exist at /upload ??????  Because if delete line upload_pass /upload  and put some random proxy_pass 127.0.0.1  and try to upload file it either gives me error 500 , or just tells me that file doen't exist ....

Comment: You should specify a backend that will handle uploaded file and return response.

Comment: And how do i do it without baackend.... If i wan't just nginx to upload the file to /tmp location adn that's all ? what should i specify to a proxy_pass ....    And maybe you can write a simple backend... and show how it should look ?  And if understand correctly this backend should be availaible at url  mydomain.com/upload ?

Comment: It's optional. It may not be available on the url. There's an example in the upload module repository: https://github.com/vkholodkov/nginx-upload-module/blob/master/example.php

Comment: Here's example from one of my applications: http://pastebin.com/YFyjnDn4 (Python)

Comment: Thanks for the example. I understand that it is optional ,  but if i remove that line upload_pass /upload (url to backend) , then i need to specify some proxy_pass to something , in order for it to work , otherwise i get error. So what proxy_pass i need to specify ? exactly to where should this proxy_pass point ?

Comment: It should point to your backend server. It does not necessarily have to be HTTP server (`proxy_pass`), it can be FastCGI (`fastcgi_pass`), uwsgi (`uwsgi_pass`) or SCGI (`scgi_pass`) backend application, that handles uploaded files (checks, moves, maybe process them somehow) and returns a response.

Comment: I see that you already have a backend in your config (I mean `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;`), so what's the problem? Probably, you should set `upload_pass /upload.php;`.

Comment: Your backend should return a 200 response code.

Comment: Thx, you are right mate :). When i create upload.php file as a backend file it works. File uplaod status is done. Strangely just when upload.php is loaded , php doesn't work in it. It just shows php as a plain text . And when file is uploaded , status is done , but file does not appear in /tmp folder. Do i need to do some magic with backend script for it to appear there , or it  should automatically be there ?

Comment: `{ "state" : "done" }` it's what the upload progress module usually returns, not your script. I think you're confusing two different and entirely independent modules: `Upload Progress` and `Upload Module`. They do different things, do you really need them both?

Comment: Emmm , what do you mean my backend should return 200 response code ?  My backend just does something what i need with the file , for example rename or move to some other folder or w/e. But file should be in tmp folde already in that directory , despite the things backend returns. and that thing that php doesn't work tehre bothers me too. I see that you return a 200 response in your php script , but for example this example https://github.com/vkholodkov/nginx-upload-module/blob/master/example.php returns nothing , so i guess it's not obligatory.  Oh my god.. i am dumb :) sorry

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14551/discussion-between-viktor-and-vbart)

Comment: Lol is there a way i can talk to you in chat ? :). that would be much simplier... skype , or msn  or any other thing... that would much quicker and easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we already discussed:
 `upload_pass /upload.php;`
;-)